# Can I salvage a tree which is broken next to its roots?

Tags: tree-care, damage, yard

There's a tree in my courtyard that has been broken very close to its roots, to the point that it cannot stand upright. Over the day, it withered.

I am not sure if it is salvageable, and the people who run the courtyard also don't know what to do. Should I fix the tree in an upright position with some supports? Should I cut and replant this tree?

There are still some fibers left between the trunk of the tree and its roots. The tree is roughly 2 m high, the trunk is 3--4 cm in diameter.

[Close-up photo of the damage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzYIx.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was nearly dead. It might resprout from the roots. It would be impractical to try to root a cutting, nothing can be done with the trunk.